# Why does this index make SELECT GROUP BY queries slower?

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, group-by

Let's say we have a table of 100k transactions (each row is a purchase of `product` by `customer` at timestamp `dt`).

I have noticed that the query

```
SELECT product, COUNT(customer) FROM transactions GROUP BY product
```

is strangely faster when there is *no index*:

|  | DB size | SELECT query time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| no index | 1.8 MB | 63 ms |
| index on `product` | 3 MB | 220 ms |
| index on `product` + index on `customer` | 4.1 MB | 292 ms |

**Why do indexes make the queries slower in this case?** (and also the database bigger, so it's a big no!)

Reproducible code:

```python
import sqlite3, time, random, string
db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
db.executescript("""CREATE TABLE transactions(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, dt INTEGER, product TEXT, customer TEXT);
                    CREATE INDEX product_idx ON transactions(product);
                    CREATE INDEX customer_idx ON transactions(customer);""")
for i in range(100*1000):
    t = random.randint(1600000000, 1600010000)                       # random datetime
    product = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=2))   # random product among 676 products
    customer = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=2))  # random customer among 676 customers
    db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions(dt, product, customer) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (t, product, customer))

t0 = time.time()
for _ in db.execute("SELECT product, COUNT(customer) FROM transactions GROUP BY product"):
    pass
print (time.time()-t0)
db.commit()
```

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` rather than `COUNT(customer)`. The latter forces it to read all the records to check if the customer is null.

Comment: Or declare the `customer` column as `NOT NULL` so it doesn't have to check this.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan in each case.

Comment: @Barmar In my real case, I have other columns too, and I want to count the number of different customers for each product (and *not* count based on these other columns), so `COUNT(*)` won't work.

Comment: @Barmar I have added `NOT NULL` to both `customer` and `product`, but the timing is the same. Would you have an idea?

Comment: @Barmar EXPLAIN says `SCAN TABLE transactions USING INDEX ...` indeed. The only way to have a `COVERING INDEX` is `CREATE INDEX idx3 ON transactions(product, customer)`, I think this is the solution (14 ms in this case, yeepee!). But this still doesn't explain why it's slower with an index on product or with an index on customer, or with two indexes (an index on product + an index on customer).

Comment: Sqlite uses one index per table in a query. When there are multiple possible ones it guesses. Sometimes in the absence of extra stats (See `pragma optimize`) it guesses wrong. Sometimes none of the indexes will work well.

Comment: Possibly without the index it has no choice but to just scan the whole table and get the column values and sort or hash them to do the `group by` But with the non covering index it can use this to avoid a sort but then needs to do lookups for every row in the table and this might take longer. Though [uses less temporary storage](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#_sorting_by_index)

Comment: Start with https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html to learn how sqlite uses indexes.

Comment: Interesting page @Shawn (as always with Sqlite doc pages), thanks!

Comment: If you want to count the number of different customers, you need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT customer)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite uses one index per table in a query. In a case like yours where there are multiple possible indexes, it guesses at which one to use. You can use [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to see which one gets picked, and [`PRAGMA optimize`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_optimize) or [`ANALYZE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) on a populated table to generate statistics that give it better information to make that guess with. It can also decide not to use any existing index, and might use an `AUTOMATIC` index, which is a temporary one built just for the query and then deleted when it's done returning rows (This naturally takes more time than using an existing index and so only happens when sqlite thinks it'll still be faster).

With an empty table:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT product, COUNT(customer) FROM transactions GROUP BY product;
QUERY PLAN
`--SCAN TABLE transactions USING INDEX product_idx
sqlite> DROP INDEX product_idx;
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT product, COUNT(customer) FROM transactions GROUP BY product;
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE transactions
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

In this case, since you group on the `product` column, that index is used. But it still has to read every row of each group to get the count of `customer`, causing a lot of disk seeking. Without any indexes, it will read the table sequentially, using a temporary data structure to build up the results. This ends up being faster (Disk reads are slow).

You can read more about how sqlite uses indexes in the [query planning](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) documentation.

The best approach here, as you've found, is to use a multi-column covering index that stores all the needed information in the index itself so the table proper never has to be consulted:

```
CREATE INDEX product_customer_idx ON transactions(product, customer);
```

Comment: Thanks! *"use a multi-column covering index that stores all the needed information in the index itself so the table proper never has to be consulted"* seems to be the solution (I also noticed that in [query planning](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html)). The only drawback is that, if in real case scenario, we have many more columns, then having a multi-column covering index will be huge, basically doubling the size of the DB or even more? Maybe I should use a `WITHOUT ROWID` table instead, and PRIMARY KEY on these multi-columns (to avoid 1 b-tree for rowid, and 1 b-tree for the index).

Comment: @Basj You have to find the sweet spot for your needs between database size, increased insert and delete time (Due to having to update indexes), and select time.

Comment: WITHOUT ROWID seems interesting @Shawn: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65470977/why-does-this-index-make-select-group-by-queries-slower/65477508#65477508

Answer (score 1):

OK, let go by parts:

> First: why is the database getting bigger with index?

It's expected the database gets bigger when adding indexes because you are adding a new support structure (the index). In this case you have:

| Structure | size |
| --- | --- |
| The db | 1.8Mb |
| The product index | 1.2Mb |
| The customer index | 1.1 Mb |

Note this sizes are an estimation.

> Why the query is getting slower with this support structures?

Maybe a bunch of reasons that justify you empirical results lets go over some possibilities

1. There is a cache that is interfering with your metrics.

This is the first thing that came to my mind, and is the first I suggest you to discard. Maybe there is some cache between those trials, try deleting and recreating everything between each test.

In your particular case this is the reason. I test your script and if you need to move your commit just before all the inserts, and after the query.

Try:

```py
import sqlite3, time, random, string
db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
db.executescript("""CREATE TABLE transactions(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, dt INTEGER, product TEXT, customer TEXT);""")
for i in range(100*1000):
    t = random.randint(1600000000, 1600010000)                       # random datetime
    product = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=2))   # random product among 676 products
    customer = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=2))  # random customer among 676 customers
    db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions(dt, product, customer) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (t, product, customer))

db.commit()
t0 = time.time()
for _ in db.execute("SELECT product, COUNT(customer) FROM transactions GROUP BY product"):
    pass
print (time.time()-t0)
db.commit()
```

I will continue explaining some possible issues an improvements but your question was already answered.

**Index suggestion**

Index are a complementary structure that fits in memory and improves the query by getting first the data you need (in the order you need).

In this case what you first need is to get all different products (the group By) and then you need to count the different customers for each product (the count), so in that case I would recommend to create a compose index like:

```
CREATE INDEX product_customer_idx 
ON transactions(product, customer)
```

So the the database engine will not go to the table in disk, instead will load all the index in memory and with a simple scan of the index will bring your answer.

**Why is this difference is no that significant in this case?**

That is simple, and you can tell by looking at the table vs index size. The index as I explained before is created to avoid fit all the table in memory (If you can fit all the table in memory, you wont get much improvement) and or to get things in the right order. In this case the order doesn't matter (you are performing a full scan with the *group by*) and if you realize the only column that is missing in the index is [**dt**] (ids are always present). So the only things that you avoid to load in memory is an integer column. Try adding some long text values in a new column, I believe that will increase the difference between the table size and the index size, and also the speed difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, comitting before the SELECT improves the speed, but then it's 63ms vs 58ms so not significantly faster with the indexes cited in my original question. Do you know why? (Feel free to elaborate in your answer). PS: I didn't downvote!

Comment: I am stil writing that, I just wanted to get your answer faster (I think that's why i got a downvote :( )

Comment: Note: "First Why the database is getting bigger with index?": this part is maybe too obvious, feel free to remove it if you want, or just leave it as a sidenote.

Comment: Thank you for your update. Note: in the case of an index on `(product, customer)`, then the improvement *is* significant indeed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65470977/why-does-this-index-make-select-group-by-queries-slower/65471508?noredirect=1#comment115750382_65470977: 14 milliseconds.

Comment: great is more clear now? Happy to help I am sure that with more columns and more data, the difference will be even bigger.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the main solution

```
CREATE INDEX product_customer_idx ON transactions(product, customer);
```

which massively improves the query, here is another way using [WITHOUT ROWID](https://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html), which produces the same result: ~ 15 milliseconds.

The benefit of using `WITHOUT ROWID` is that only 1 B-tree is used (for the primary key), and not one B-tree for `rowid` and one B-tree for the index like with the other method. Benefit: 2 MB database size vs. 3.3 MB.

```python
db.executescript("""CREATE TABLE transactions(id INTEGER, dt INTEGER, product TEXT, customer TEXT,
                        PRIMARY KEY(product, customer, id)) WITHOUT ROWID;""")

for i in range(100*1000):
    t = random.randint(1600000000, 1600010000)                       # random datetime
    product = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=2))   # random product among 676 products
    customer = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=2))  # random customer among 676 customers
    db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions(id, dt, product, customer) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 
        (i, t, product, customer))
```